# Is any mono a split mono (in abelian categories)?

Tags: category-theory, abelian-categories

I read on Ugo Bruzzo's *Derived Functors and Sheaf Cohomology*, in the paragraph below *Definition 1.6*, that in an abelian category $f:a\to a'$ is monic iff there is $l:a'\to a$ such that $l\circ f=1_a$. The "only if" doesn't seem true to me, as for example $\mathbb Z\to \mathbb Z$ defined by $1\mapsto 2$ is injective and not left-invertible in the category of abelian groups. Am I misinterpreting something, or did I miss something about the definitions in an abelian category? It seems strange that it is a mistake of the book, because it couldn't be just a typo, it is an entire paragraph. Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: This is false and your counterexample is correct. Can you post the entire paragraph in which this appears? There may be extra context.

Comment: Are you sure that $l$ is supposed to be a morphism and not just a set theoretic map? Because if it is just a set theoretic map it just says that being monic in an abelian category, where the objects "are" sets, is equivalent to it being injective, which I think is true. But if it actually is  meant to be a morphism it is definitelynot true.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I added a screenshot from page 9, the previous pages basically just contain the definitions of category and epi/mono/iso.

Comment: @linkja I initially thought the same, but it really seems that $f$ and $l$ are both in (the abelian category) $\mathfrak A$

Comment: There seems to be a proliferation of texts with basic mistakes these days…

Comment: I would not keep reading this text if I were you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Monomorphisms in abelian categories need not be split. In fact, $A\to B$ is split if and only if the sequence $$0\to A \to B\to A/B\to 0$$
is split exact, which is the case if and only if $B = A\oplus A/B$, the first map is the inclusion of the coproduct and the second map the projection of the second factor. This is the [splitting lemma](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/split+exact+sequence). There wouldn't be a name for split exact sequences, if all short exact sequences would be split exact.

Since $\mathbb Z \neq \mathbb Z\oplus \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$, your example is correct. The sequence $$0\to \mathbb Z \xrightarrow{\cdot 2} \mathbb Z\to \mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z \to 0$$
is not split, but exact.

In a category of $R$-modules for $R$ a ring all monomorphisms are split if and only if the ring $R$ is semisimple.